# Adicionar espaço a cada letra em MAIÚSCULA

Tags: php

Como dar espaço usando PHP quando começar uma palavra em maiúsculo, por exemplo, a *string* `oiEusouMuitoLegal` resultar em `oi Eusou Muito Legal`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Para fazer isso você pode utilizar a seguinte *regex*, *`/(?<!\ )[A-Z]/`*.

```php
$str = "oiEusouMuitoLegal";
echo preg_replace('/(?<!\ )[A-Z]/', ' $0', $str);
// oi Eusou Muito Legal
```

[**`Ideone`**](http://ideone.com/tmtqmG)

O trecho `(?<!\ )` é uma afirmação de que irá certificar-se que não adicionar um espaço antes de uma letra maiúscula que já tem um espaço antes dele.

[**`Fonte`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1089681/1608936)

Comment: Quando vamos ter uma expressão regular para nos tirar um cafézito fresquinho pela manhã? ;) +1

Comment: É só um palpite não testado, mas acho que a regex `([^^ ])([A-Z])`, com replace pra `$1 $2` também funciona.

Comment: @Zuul, avisem-me que estou a precisar dela!

Answer (score 5):

Já tens uma resposta que sem dúvida é o caminho a seguir, fica um exemplo para quem não quer usar expressões regulares:

```
$texto = "oiEusouMuitoLegal";

$letras = preg_split('//', $texto, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

foreach ($letras as $letra) {

    if (ctype_upper($letra)) {
        $texto = str_replace($letra, " $letra", $texto);
    }
}

echo $texto;  // Saída: oi Eusou Muito Legal
```

Exemplo no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/IOacPC).

---

<sup>Código lida com o problema na pergunta e ilustra a complexidade de trabalhar uma *string* sem fazer uso de expressões regulares para operações baseadas num padrão repetitivo.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

```
echo preg_replace('/\B[A-Z]/', ' $0', "Olá oiEusouMuitoLegal! Tem Dias...");
//Olá oi Eusou Muito Legal! Tem Dias...
```